# How do I calculate standard deviation in python without using numpy?

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, mean, standard-deviation

I'm trying to calculate standard deviation in python without the use of `numpy` or any external library except for `math`. I want to get better at writing algorithms and am just doing this as a bit of "homework" as I improve my python skills. My goal is to translate [this formula](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html) into python but am not getting the correct result.

I'm using an array of speeds where `speeds = [86,87,88,86,87,85,86]`

When I run:

```
std_dev = numpy.std(speeds)
print(std_dev)
```

I get: 0.903507902905. But I don't want to rely on numpy. So...

My implementation is as follows:

```
import math

speeds = [86,87,88,86,87,85,86]

def get_mean(array):
    sum = 0
    for i in array:
        sum = sum + i
    mean = sum/len(array)
    return mean

def get_std_dev(array):
    # get mu
    mean = get_mean(array)
    # (x[i] - mu)**2
    for i in array:
        array = (i - mean) ** 2
        return array
    sum_sqr_diff = 0
    # get sigma
    for i in array:
        sum_sqr_diff = sum_sqr_diff + i
        return sum_sqr_diff
    # get mean of squared differences
    variance = 1/len(array)
    mean_sqr_diff = (variance * sum_sqr_diff)
    
    std_dev = math.sqrt(mean_sqr_diff)
    return std_dev

std_dev = get_std_dev(speeds)
print(std_dev)
```

Now when I run:

```
std_dev = get_std_dev(speeds)
print(std_dev)
```

I get: `[0]` but I am expecting 0.903507902905

What am I missing here?

Comment: `math` is not an external library.

Comment: what is your input? how we can reproduce that answer?

Comment: You are defining speeds and calling it with narrow_speed.  Doesn't that give you an error?

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin All the code was available in the question body but it wasn't all in the same block. I have edited the part where I show my implementation to include everything necessary to reproduce.

Comment: Your code is not returning `[0]` !

Comment: @cup You're right, thank you for pointing that out! I modified the code I was working with for a minimal example and forgot to change the variable name. I updated my code to call `get_std_dev` with `speeds`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What are you getting when you run it?

Comment: Your first mistake: `return array`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you elaborate?

Comment: You return a number, so the result can't be `[0]`, as that's a list.

Comment: @YvesDaoust `array = (i - mean) ** 2` comes earlier.

Comment: @KellyBundy: why do you tell me ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just pointing out your comment is mistaken.

Comment: @KellyBundy: my comment is not mistaken. I am pointing an error in the OP's post. The code is not returning `[0]` as he describes (and I know very well why it doesn't). By the way, the OP made no effort to fix the text.

Comment: @YvesDaoust `array = (i - mean) ** 2` is another mistake and it comes earlier than `return array`, so no, `return array` is *not* their first mistake. You're mistaken.

Comment: @KellyBundy: ok, I didn't know you were referring to my second comment.

Comment: @KellyBundy: anyway, the assignment to `array` is the first coding mistake in the program text, but at run-time the `return` statement results in a problem *before* the assignment does. At this stage, assigning `array` does no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
speeds = [86,87,88,86,87,85,86]

# Calculate the mean of the values in your list
mean_speeds = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)

# Calculate the variance of the values in your list
# This is 1/N * sum((x - mean(X))^2)
var_speeds = sum((x - mean_speeds) ** 2 for x in speeds) / len(speeds)

# Take the square root of variance to get standard deviation
sd_speeds = var_speeds ** 0.5

>>> sd_speeds
0.9035079029052513
```

Comment: When I run that I get `1.0`.

Comment: Restart your python kernel. Something you've done has screwed with one of the built-in functions.

Comment: Oh, never mind, you're using python2.7, arent you. Add `from __future__ import division` - the standard division `/` is not true division until python 3.0 unless you import from future.

Comment: yes I'm using 2.7. Your solution plus the future division import is working for me now. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: It's time to move to py3, mate.

Comment: I'm pretty new to python and I haven't yet figured out the rhyme or reason as to when my machine runs py2 vs py3 to be honest. I'll have to get that sorted out.

Comment: A lot of linux distros ship with py2.7 and py3 - you probably have python3 (but the binary is `python3` instead of just `python`). You can also consider using something like anaconda to set up environments. py2.7 is well past end-of-life.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is the reuse of array and return in the middle of the loop

```
def get_std_dev(array):
    # get mu
    mean = get_mean(array)       <-- this is 86.4
    # (x[i] - mu)**2
    for i in array:
        array = (i - mean) ** 2  <-- this is almost 0
        return array             <-- this is the value returned
```

Now let us look at the algorithm you are using.  Note that there are two std deviation formulas that are commonly used.  There are various arguments as to which one is correct.

```
sqrt(sum((x - mean)^2) / n)
```

or

```
sqrt(sum((x - mean)^2) / (n -1))
```

For big values of n, the first formula is used since the -1 is insignificant.  The first formula can be reduced to

```
sqrt(sum(x^2) /n - mean^2)
```

So how would you do this in python?

```
def std_dev1(array):
   n = len(array)
   mean = sum(array) / n
   sumsq = sum(v * v for v in array)
   return (sumsq / n - mean * mean) ** 0.5
```

Answer (score -1):

some problems in the code, one of them is the return value inside the for statement. you can try this

```
def get_mean(array):
    return sum(array) / len(array)


def get_std_dev(array):
    n = len(array)
    mean = get_mean(array)
    squares_arr = []
    for item in array:
        squares_arr.append((item - mean) ** 2)
    return math.sqrt(sum(squares_arr) / n)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use `numpy` its ok give a try to `statistics` package in python

```
import statistics

st_dev = statistics.pstdev(speeds)
print(st_dev)
```

or if you are still willing to use a custom solution then I recommend you to use the following way using list comprehension instead of your complex buggy approach

```
import math

mean = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
var = sum((l-mean)**2 for l in speeds) / len(speeds)
st_dev = math.sqrt(var)
print(st_dev)
```